# Angular unit tests / mocking forkJoin

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, fork-join

I am working in Angular 9 using Jest & Spectator and trying to write unit tests for a component.
The problem is that in my ngOnInit() I have a forkJoin making some calls to my facades and then, in the subscribe, assigning the returned values to the correct variables.

When my tests run I get this error:

```
TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.

      81 |       myData1: this.facade1.findThisThing(),
      82 |       myData2: this.facade2.findThatThing(),
    > 83 |     }).subscribe(data => {
         |        ^
      84 |       this.data1 = data.myData1.values;
      85 |       this.data2 = data.myData2.values;
```

How do I mock this subscribe / handle it ?

Component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    forkJoin({
      myData1: this.facade1.findThisThing(),
      myData2: this.facade2.findThatThing(),

    }).subscribe(data => {
      this.data1 = data.myData1.values;
      this.data2 = data.myData2.values;
    });
}
```

I thought by maybe putting it in the providers array, in the component.spec, when I create the component via the createComponentFactory method but that did not seem to help.

component.spec:

```
const createComponent = createComponentFactory<ComponentUnderTest>(
    {
      component: ComponentUnderTest,
      mocks: [
       ...
      ]
      providers: [
        {
          provide: 'subscribe',
          useValue: jest.fn()
        }
      ],
      shallow: true,
    },
  );
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you so much Stack Overflow community!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is actually not the subscribe statement itself. What you want to do is mocking the service and therefore mocking the return value of the functions that you use inside the forkJoin. Do notice that rxjs is as synchronous as possible so if you would return an Observable created with the `of` operator it is entirely synchronous. So you could mock the function and return an observable leveraging the `of` operator.

The problem that you face is actually happening because one of the functions that you pass to forkJoin is returning `undefined`. Do notice if you are leveraging jasmine spy for mocking Angular services, if you don't specify the return value of a function, that you are spying, it will return undefined.

Answer (score 0):

read about spy on and mock both your methods inside forkjoin.
something like

spyOn(this.facade1.findThisThing).and.returnValue(of());

same for secondMethod.